# Auto open virtual Keyboard in Linux (Debian) if text to be entered?

Tags: linux, debian, virtual-keyboard

Is there any possibility to auto open an on-screen virtual keyboard in Debian to when the focus is set to a text field?
The behaviour should be like in iOS or Android app...

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

So it seems as if you can solve your problem using [Florence Virtual Keyboard](https://packages.debian.org/sid/web/florence). As stated in its package description it "stays out of your way: it appears on the screen only when needed."

Comment: And if Florence doesn't suit, its documentation does suggest [alternatives](http://florence.sourceforge.net/english/alternatives.html).

Comment: No. It doesn't appear automatically. I have to call it. I need something that reacts like a system wide event which tells the keyboatd to showup it it is needed.